# I want to know the existing of the device by bluetooth getRemoteDevice function or other function

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I`m sorry about not good English skill.

I want to know that the device exists which has the mac address.
I used  the getRemoteDevice method from BluetoothAdapter.
But the document said,
'A BluetoothDevice will always be returned for a valid hardware address, even if this adapter has never seen that device.'
So I couldn`t know the existing of the device.

How can I know the exists of the device?

Below code is my previous code. But I can`t know how to change the null checking.

```java
public void connectSavedDevice() {
        String result = pref.getString("first_device", "0");
        if(result.equals("0")) {
            Log.d(TAG,"not saved device");
            return;
        }

        BluetoothDevice device = ble_adapter_.getRemoteDevice(result); 
        if(device == null) {
            editor.clear();
            editor.commit();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                startScan();
            }
            return;
        }
        GattClientCallback gatt_client_cb= new GattClientCallback();
        ble_gatt_= device.connectGatt( context, false, gatt_client_cb );
    }
```

Comment: you will have to scan for it, or try to connect to it to check if it is nearby. You can't check if it exists somewhere in the world.

Comment: You mean I have to try to connect GATT if I want to check the device exists nearby? 
I am hard to scan because the scanning takes a lot of time.
Thank you.

Comment: yes. Or you may scan for this device (if it is broadcasting)

Comment: The server device is broadcasting. I think I have to study about the bluetooth scanning. Thank you very much for help. :)